# PTIJ: Behavior when visiting a chair factory

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

North Carolina, in particular, is well-known for making quality furniture, especially chairs and benches. My friend and I plan on visiting one of these chair factories, soon. But I was puzzled by finding an chapter in *Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim* called:

הנהגת בית הכסא

Behavior in a chair house

Among the behavior rules is:

> ולא ילכו שני אנשים ביחד, גם לא ידבר שם

Two people should not visit a chair house (I assume a factory that makes just chairs qualifies as a chair house.) So, my friend can't join me? We have to go in separately?

And, it also says that no one should talk there. How am I supposed to communicate with the salespeople or the store manager? By signing or only writing things down or WhatsApp?

Why are there these conduct restrictions, among others, applicable to visiting a chair factory? What's so special about chairs?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: consult the relevant section in the Seats Eliezer.

Answer (score 9):

You're looking in the Shulchan Aruch edition of this. As the name suggests, this is for those who are going to have a "set table," i.e. to stay for a while.

You say you're going to "visit." As such, you ought to see what the Tour version of this has to say, and in [his version](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.3) there's no mention of these halachos.

Comment: that hit the spot!